# form_for building in rails, what can someone infer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I had a general question of what is going on when code like this runs:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.favorite_relationships.find_by_lesson_id(@lesson),
             html: {method: :delete},
             remote: true) do |f| %>
             <div><%= f.hidden_field :lesson_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Unfavorite", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

specifically the very first line of code. i usually see some form of instance variable instead of

```
current_user.favorite_relationships.find_by_lesson_id
```

I can assume that this will go into the `FavoriteRelationship` controller's destroy action. Is there anything else someone can infer from that form above? Like what will be available or gets passed in the destroy action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the controller has supplied a `Lesson` object to the view through the variable `@lesson`. Your current user, a `User` object, presumably `has_many :favorite_relationships`, which in turn `belongs_to :lesson`, meaning there is a field within the `favorite_relationships` table called `lesson_id`.

Rails builds "magic" finder methods for your models for the fields it contains. If a model has a `lesson_id` field, Rails provides a `find_by_lesson_id` helper. Rails is smart enough to extract `@lesson.id` when you pass it an actual Lesson object instead of an integer.

The net result is that an object of type `FavoriteRelationship` is being passed into the `form_for` helper. This is no different than finding the object in the controller and passing it to the view via a (for example) `@favorite_relationship` variable.

> what will be available or gets passed in the destroy action?

The only thing available to the controller on the subsequent request to the FavoriteRelationship's destroy route is the id of the object to destroy. You'll be able to access it via `params[:id]`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The destroy action is via AJAX (presence of `remote: true`)
2. In general, the main logic/code is refactored into either a controller or a helper method.

The `@favorites = current_user.favorite_relationships.find_by_lesson_id(@lesson)`, IMO, should be placed inside the controller rather than the view and the view should have `@favourites` in the `form_for` part. That is the reason for the observation you've made about instance variables